# Axios and vue-resource put method doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

I have on front vuejs and on backend java. In one component I bring the users from the database.

Users.vue

```
getUsers() {
  this.$http.get("/user")
    .then((response) => {
      this.users = response.data.users;
    })
}
```

Still here I use v-for to bring all users in another component User.vue.

```
<app-user v-for="user in users" :user="user" :key="user.index"></app-user>
```

In user component I have a router link that takes me to another page where I can edit the username.

User.vue

```
 <p class="user-name">{{user.firstName}}</p>
 <router-link :to="'/users/edit-user/'+user.id">
    <a ><i class="ti-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
 </router-link>
```

EditUser.vue

```
    <template>
      <input type="text" :value="user.firstName" v-model="userInfo.firstName">
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          user: {},
          userInfo: {
            firstName: '',
          }
        }
      },
      created() {
        this.getUsers();
      },
      methods: {
        getUsers() {
          this.$http.get("/user/" + this.$route.params.id)
            .then((response) => {
              this.user = response.data;
            })
        },
        updateUser() {
          axios.put('/user', this.userInfo,  
            {'headers':{'X-AUTH-TOKEN':localStorage.token}},
            {'headers':{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("Success! You edited the user"); 

          })
          .catch((response) => {
            console.log('Error in edit');
          })
        }
      },
    }
    </script>
```

I started learning vuejs a month ago and still have to learn :).

In the input I use `:value="user.firstName"` to bring the value for firstName that already exists. I try to use `v-model="userInfo.firstName"` to get new value for userName, but when I put this, the value, that existed already, disappears from the input.

To save data with post works fine but only with axios. I don't know why post doesn't work with vue-resource. So I tried put with axios too, but what I edit when I press save button, on EditUser.vue, my request doesn't go to server.

I say this because I saw that in the backend I don't get any error, nothing, but if I use post or get I can get or save users.

What do I do wrong in my code that I don't edit the user?

Comment: you should decide to either use axios or vue-resource - I'd prefer axios since vue-resource will not be developed any further. A put is usually a "full update" / "replacement" of an existing entity. You cannot "put" to the /user endpoint because put is meant to be used for existing entities. Use post for creating a new one. (if you follow default rest behaviour)

Comment: I tried with post too, but still nothing. Axios or vue-resource, I still learn, doesn't matter now my friend, because I saw witch one how works on create user, with post, and bring user. But for edit the user none of them works.

Comment: without seeing your routes definition and or your corresponding code in the controller it's hard to tell where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your axios implementation. Seems to me that you are updating to the general /users/ route. This works for post, since no user id exists yet, so a new one will be created. However, if you use PUT, a user id does exist. So I think you should modify your endpoint to be /user/:userid instead of just /user. Hopes this helps.

From restapitutorial dot com/lessons/httpmethods.html:

Examples:

- POST http://www.example.com/customers
- PUT http://www.example.com/customers/12345

Comment: I tried my friend with id too, but still the data doesn't edit(send with the new value) :( . `axios.put('/user/' + this.$route.params.id, this.userInfo`

Comment: The only other thing that I can think of is that you define two header objects like this: `{'headers':{'X-AUTH-TOKEN':localStorage.token}},
            {'headers':{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}`. I think you need to pass 1 headers object like this: `{'headers':{'X-AUTH-TOKEN':localStorage.token,'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}`. If that's not the problem, I really can't see without seeing an error log (client or server side).

Comment: With axios I don't get anything in the console for success or error, for put or post. With this.$http-resource I get for post and put the error: `Response {url: "/user/46", ok: false, status: 0, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …} `

Comment: Ok last thing I can do is give you some general pointers and hope that will work. 1) Use axios, not vue-resource. It is actually recommended by VueJS team to use axios. 2) Check the tab "network" in your console to see if the request is made and what response code it is giving. 3) Use a tool like https://www.getpostman.com/ to send a put request to your backend. Usually, using something outside of your code helps you to at least get your requests right. That way, you can be sure that there is an error at client side and take the bug fixing from there.

Comment: Like I said above my friend axios.post to add a new user works fine: ```axios.post('/user', this.userInfo`, {'headers':{'X-AUTH-TOKEN': localStorage.token}}, {'headers':{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})```. But for put, in the network I get the same value for username not the new one.